# Do two points determine a unique line in 4D space?

Tags: geometry

I wish to generalize the notion of two points determining a unique line to four dimensions, but with the additional condition that all points on the line are a unit distance from the origin and the "line" is not straight, but forms a least-distance curve between the two points. This is easy to do in the case of three dimensions: the line is a great circle and is defined by p.x=0, where p is found by the cross product of the two points. But I can't seem to generalize this to four dimensions. Is there not a unique geodesic curve that passes through two points? If there is, how would I express it in terms of the two points?

Comment: So your points and line are all suppose to lie in the sphere, $S^3$?

Comment: In the $3D$ case, two point determine a unique great circle unless they are antipodal. Same statement holds for $S^n$. The great circle is the intersection of the sphere and the plane passing through the two points and the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're just trying to carry out the picture of spherical geometry in 3-D to 4-D.

In the 3-D picture, the surface of the unit sphere is taken to be the set of points, and the "lines" are the great circles. Any two points which aren't antipodal determine a unique great circle.

The way to look at the great circle in that case is as the intersection of a plane through the origin with the sphere. This is suggestive then that you are looking for the intersection of the plane through your two points and the origin in 4-D, and the line should be the intersection of this plane with the sphere $S_3$.

Looking at it from this perspective, you can believe that two nonantipodal points with the origin of 4-space form a noncollinear set of three points, and hence a unique plane.

Comment: I've tried to do what you suggest, find a unique plane through the two points and the origin in 4-space. Suppose a and b are my two points. A plane would be defined as the intersection of two hyperplanes, p.x=0 and q.x=0. These two hyperplanes already go through the origin, so to make them contain the two points, a and b, we would have p.a=0 p.b=0, q.a=0, and q.b=0. This gives four equations, but there are 8 unknown parameters, (p1, p2, p3, p4) and (q1, q2, q3, q4). So it seems that there is not a unique plane through two 4D points and the origin. What am I missing?

Comment: Dear @8bar : well for one thing, I was approaching it by defining a plane to be a 2 dimensional subspace. You would just take the subspace generated by the vectors pointing from the origin to your two points. Basic linear algebra tells you that any other plane containing the points would have to contain these two vectors, and so it would coincide with the plane we chose.

Comment: I, too, was assuming a 2 dimensional subspace. The intersection of two hyperplanes (each 3-dimensional) should be 2-dimensional, right? I understand that a plane can be described as a linear combination of two basis vectors, but is there some fundamental reason why a plane can't be expressed in equation form in 4D space? I can describe a plane in 3-space as p1x1 + p2x2 + p3x3 + p4 = 0, so can't I do something similar in 4 dimensions to describe the equation for a plane? I assume it would require a pair of equations, similar to how a line is described by equations in 3-space.

Comment: @8bar Sure you can find equations. It just amounts to computing the kernel (on the right) of the matrix formed by using the two vectors as rows. Finding any two linearly independent vectors in the kernel is enough to give you a system of equations that completely describes the plane. The intersection of hyperplanes picture is right conceptually, it just seems like we can cut to the chase by computing the complement directly :)

Answer (score 0):

The origin and the 2 given points determine a plane in 4-space, so now you can use your "line" in that plane.

Comment: Please see my response below to rschwieb, since he has a similar response to yours.

Comment: @8bar If the two points are v, w then the plane has exactly the points $sv+tw$ for scalars $s,t$. You could find two vectors perpendicular to this plane and thereby determine this plane as the intersection of two 3-dimensional hyperplanes.

Comment: I see. And the two normal vectors are not unique. I see the flaw in my reasoning in my initial response to @rschwieb. I was assuming that the pair of hyperplanes would be unique. But obviously they need not be, just as how there are an infinite number of pairs of planes in 3-space that define one specific line.

Answer (score 0):

For any given surface with a metric, there are some differential equations you can solve in order to determine what a geodesic looks like. In your case the surface is the three-sphere, $S^3$, and a metric can be found on the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere under hyper-spherical coordinates. The differential equations for a geodesic can then be found by some calculus of variations. I suggest you first see how this works out for $S^2$.